# Tkinter Calculator can you guys tell me how to fix the problem and let the answer show up

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
def tkinter_calculator():
    window=Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    l1=Label(window,text="Welcome to Calculator")
    l1.pack()
    e1=Entry(window,width=10,bd=4)
    e1.place(x=300,y=300)
    l2=Label(window,text="+")
    l2.place(x=500,y=300)
    e2=Entry(window,width=10,bd=4)
    e2.place(x=600,y=300)
    l3=Label(window,text="=")
    l3.place(x=750,y=300)
    def add_ops():
        global e1
        num1 = e1.get()
        global e2
        
        num2=e2.get()
        addVal = int(num1) + int(num2)
        output=Label(window, text=w"Your answer is" + int(addVal)) 
        output.place(x=300,y=300)     
    add_ops()
    b1=Button(window,text="Calculate",fg="blue",bg="silver",command=add_ops)
    b1.place(x=850,y=300)
    
    
    window.mainloop()
tkinter_calculator()
```

I expected a text showing up the answer
I expected two textboxes and a calculate button and when I press the button it should calculate and show what the answer is so that it functions like a basic calculator

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

- you can only see the label `l1` because other widgets are put in the window using `.place()` which will not adjust the window size. You need to specify the initial size of the window in order to see those widgets.
- `e1` and `e2` are local variables inside `tkinter_calculator()`, so they cannot be found when they are accessed inside `add_ops()` because they are declared as global variables.  Remove `global e1` and `global e2`.
- `add_ops()` is called before creating the `Calculate` button, so it will raise `ValueError` exception when calling `int()` on the content of the two entry boxes because there is nothing input in the two entries yet. Remove that line.
- extra `w` in `w"..."`
- new label for the result will be created when `Calculate` button is clicked.  Create `output` label once outside `add_ops()` and update its text inside that function.
- you cannot concatenate integer to string, so `"Your answer is" + int(addVal)` will raise exception.  Change it to `"Your answer is "+str(addVal)`.

Below is the updated `tkinter_calculator()`:

```py
def tkinter_calculator():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    window.geometry("1000x400") # give initial window size
    l1 = Label(window, text="Welcome to Calculator")
    l1.pack()
    e1 = Entry(window, width=10, bd=4)
    e1.place(x=300, y=300)
    l2 = Label(window, text="+")
    l2.place(x=500, y=300)
    e2 = Entry(window, width=10, bd=4)
    e2.place(x=600, y=300)
    l3 = Label(window, text="=")
    l3.place(x=750, y=300)
    def add_ops():
        num1 = e1.get()
        num2 = e2.get()
        addVal = int(num1) + int(num2)
        # update output label
        output.config(text="Your answer is "+str(addVal))
    b1 = Button(window, text="Calculate", fg="blue", bg="silver", command=add_ops)
    b1.place(x=850, y=300)
    # create output label once
    output = Label(window)
    output.place(x=300, y=350)
    window.mainloop()
```

---

To better control the layout of the widgets, `.grid()` is recommended over `.place()`.  Below is the modified `tkinter_calculator()` using `.grid()` instead of `.place()`:

```py
def tkinter_calculator():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    window.config(padx=10)

    l1 = Label(window, text="Welcome to Calculator")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=10)

    e1 = Entry(window, width=10, bd=4)
    e1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    l2 = Label(window, text="+")
    l2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

    e2 = Entry(window, width=10, bd=4)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=2)

    l3 = Label(window, text="=")
    l3.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5)

    def add_ops():
        try:
            num1 = int(e1.get())
            num2 = int(e2.get())
            output.config(text=f"Your answer is {num1+num2}")
        except ValueError as ex:
            output.config(text="Please enter valid numbers")

    b1 = Button(window, text="Calculate", fg="blue", bg="silver", command=add_ops)
    b1.grid(row=1, column=4)

    output = Label(window)
    output.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=10)

    window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]